# Performance issue in a system with better configuration

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, performance

I am running one line code on my laptop which is taking around 45 minutes whereas same line of code on same dataset is taking less than 2 minutes on another laptop. Below are the configuration of my laptop/other one and resource utilization of both laptops during the run of code.
Please suggest why my laptop performance is so poor and if I can do anything to make it better.

My Laptop- For full specs, please visit https://www.flipkart.com/acer-predator-helios-300-core-i5-8th-gen-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-128-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-ph315-51-gaming-laptop/p/itmf4echjawprzsp?pid=COMF4ECHAUTZ7F5Y&srno=s_1_3&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_0_10&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_0_10&lid=LSTCOMF4ECHAUTZ7F5YNVVTQ0&fm=SEARCH&iid=4a804169-c1d2-4770-b2ea-139522fc15d0.COMF4ECHAUTZ7F5Y.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=8utc3xx6gw0000001562765195185&qH=98e5b841d6fdf242

For comparing both processors, please visit at https://versus.com/en/intel-core-i5-8265u-vs-intel-core-i5-8300h

My Laptop details- 1TB HDD, 128GB SSD, 8GB RAM, 4GB GPU
Processor- Intel(R) Core (TM) i5-8300H CPU @2.30 GHz 2.30 GHz
Utilization: Memory - 42% , CPU- 22%, DISK- 0%, NETWORK- 0%, GPU -0%

Other laptop- 1TB HDD, No SSD, 8GB RAM, 4GB GPU.
Processor- Intel(R) Core (TM) i5-8265U CPU @1.60 GHz 1.80 GHz
Utilization: Memory- 61% , CPU- 3%, DISK- 0%, NETWORK- 0%, GPU -0%

Comment: Sorry, but those specs are very hard to read and compare. Also, I don't understand what "All kind of memory sizes are same and 4GB GPU" means. You can [edit] your question to improve it. You should also add information about hard disk types (HDD or SSD or hybrid/SSHD).

Comment: @gronostaj- Thanks. As per your suggestion, I have just updated my question with more details.

Comment: Pull up a task manager and see whats causing the bottleneck. My guess +and cant do more then that) is that the command is processing a large data file which is located on SSD on the fast machine and HDD on the slow one.(or swap/paging file is on swap vs ssd)

Comment: @davidgo, in task manager it was showing "Python" as the most consuming resources process which I was running for code. I tried by moving file from SSD to HDD and still facing same challenge. Any further guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: You misunderstood me - I was suggesting looking at whether the disk UI was very high or CPU, so you can work out what resource.is the bottleneck and narrow the problem space.

Comment: @davidgo, I have included the resource utilization of both laptops in my query. Although my CPU utilization was higher(22%) but I also tried by reducing it to 3% with no gain.